# Products.Carousel uninstall seems to be leaving leftover contents

Tags: plone

I'm testing Products.Carousel before to install it on a web site in production.

While uninstalling the product via the quick_installer went smoothly, the banners are still present in their folder (while only being reachable via the "Contents" tab of the parent folder or through the ZMI).

Is is safe to delete this folder manually? Should this be considered a bug in Products.Carousel - i.e. should I file a bug report?

Tia

Answer (score 5):

The uninstall implementation should never touch your content (This is a scary imagination imho). It should uninstall the configuration aka GenericSetup steps.

If you uninstall a certain package, which has it's own content types you should remove them (created objs) manually before uninstall the package.

So, no bug report necessary.

Comment: OK, thank you so much.While I do agree there should be no data removal without prior user/admin approval, I think that would be cool to have this as an option since removing a product generally means you want to get rid of related contents. Just like removing a user account on a (shared) computer relates for 95 % to removing also the user's files. Besides, what will happen if after uninstalling the product through the control panel one re-run buildout _before_ to remove the related contents : shall those contents be accessible again - in order to be removed at least?

Comment: @phep: I'd ask the authors of the addon.

Comment: I do not fully agree with you, removing a user account is not the same use-case as removing a addon from a application server. You may have a dependency chain and so it's not always clear, who is responsible for which content. imho you have to get rid of this before removing the addon.